# Deep copy of NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can one deep-copy the contents of an NSMutableDictionary to another NSMutableDictionary?

I do not want to use initWithDictionary:copyItems: method as my dictionaries are already initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
- (void)addEntriesFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)otherDictionary
```

This copies the Keys, But not the values, of an `NSDictionary`. Of course, If you need a deep copy, take a look at this:

```
@interface NSDictionary(rross)

- (void)addEntriesFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)otherDictionary copyItems:(BOOL) copyItems;

@end

@implementation NSDictionary(rross)

- (void)addEntriesFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)otherDictionary copyItems:(BOOL) copyItems
{
     if (copyItems)
     {
         // get the keys
         NSArray *oldKeys = [otherDictionary allKeys];

         for (int i = 0; i < oldKeys.count; i++)
         {
              // add all the new key / value pairs
              id key = [oldKeys objectAtIndex:i];
              [self setObject:[[[otherDictionary objectForKey:key] copy] autorelease] forKey:[[key copy] autorelease]];
         }
    }
    else
    {
         [self addEntriesFromOtherDictionary:otherDictionary];
    }
}

@end
```